# Location of unhandled exception is incorrect when debugging F# code on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, f#

When debugging C# code, Visual Studio shows the original location of unhandled exception.

For example, when debugging following code, Visual Studio shows the unhandled DivideByZeroException was thrown at line 9.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Func()
        {
            throw new DivideByZeroException(); // line 9
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try { Func(); }
            catch (ArgumentException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do the same thing in F#. Following is my translation of above code into F#.

```
open System

let f() = raise (new DivideByZeroException()) // line 3

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    try 
        f()
    with :? ArgumentException -> () // line 9
    0
```

When I debug this code on Visual Studio, it breaks for unhandled exception and points line 9. I expect it points line 3.

I tried Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.reraise but it didn't change the result.

**EDIT**

C# debug screen capture

[image: Debugging screen, C#]

F# debug screen capture

[image: Debugging screen, F#]

Generated IL for C#

[image: ILSpy for C#]

Generated IL for F#

[image: ILSpy for F#]

Comment: I bet the compiler has inlined the function at call site. Are you building with optimizations enabled? Can you look at the compiled code with ILSpy?

Comment: Optimization is not enabled. I checked it using ILSpy. It looks like not inlined, it calls 'rethrow' instruction. But not sure because it is hard to read.

Comment: Interestingly, IL for C# code doesn't use 'rethrow' instruction because it only catches ArgumentException. Generated IL for F# catches System.Object and inspects it by generated code, and when didin't match it calls 'rethrow' instruction. So there was difference in IL code.

Comment: @Noro: It would be great if you could add details to your question, about how the IL looks like in the different cases.

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you added the try/with statement in your call to f(), the thrown exception was propagated to that point of your code which is in the 'main' block.

In order to handle the exception in function f() as in your C# example, move the  try/with to f(), like this:

```
let f() = 
 try
   raise (System.DivideByZeroException()) // exception is handled here
   with | InnerError(str) -> printfn "Error1 %s" str

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    f()
    0
```

Comment: Yes, it is better to handle exception as early as possible. But when I get a unhandled exception due to a bug unexpectedly, I have to locate the bug. In my example I was expecting ArgumentException so Func() call is in try {} block. But didn't expect DivideByZeroException caused by bug. Problem is for above example Visual Studio debugger helps when I use C# but doesn't when I use F#. Apologize if my question was unclear.

Comment: @Nozo The problem is that F# does not perform exception handling in the same way as C# (as you have discovered).  One thing you can do at the expense of some code clutter is to do use #if DEBUG to perform excpetion handling one way when you are debuggin and the other way in release mode.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It will be an effective workaround. In my example I will disable try-catch for ArgumentException when in debug.

Comment: Sure. happy to help.  I guess one can have their cake and eat it too :-)

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem and [filed an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3297).  A workaround is to add `--generate-filter-blocks` to the "Other flags" in the "Build" page of the project properties.